# Is it possible to get multiple values from XCOM for a single task at once in Airflow?

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

Is it possible to retrieve multiple values from XCOM, pushed by a single task but with different keys?

I think I've seen examples to this:

```
# pulls one value
pulled_value = ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids='my_task_id')
```

and to this:

```
# pulls multiple values but from multiple tasks
pulled_value_1, pulled_value_2 = ti.xcom_pull(key=None, task_ids=['my_task_id_1', 'my_task_id_2'])
```

What I need is would possibly look like this:

```
# pulls multiple values but from a single
pulled_value_1, pulled_value_2 = ti.xcom_pull(key=['my_key_1', 'my_key_2'], task_ids='my_task_id')
```

I can't find this in the documentation.
Is this even possible?
If yes, it makes a single database query in the background, or just repeats a single query multiple times?
If not, how could I get similar behavior?

Comment: I've checked the current master branch (https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/models/xcom.py), and I did not find any possible function to handle this requirement, although in some use cases it could reduce the load on database. Would it be useful to add a feature like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. There is no such feature.
   `xcom_pull` accepts `task_ids: Optional[Union[str, Iterable[str]]]` but with the same key. You can open a PR to Airflow for adding the functionality you seek.
2. As for number of queries: I assume that by "repeats a single query" you are asking if it execute a query per `task_id`. The answer is No. Airflow did this optimization in [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6461).
   In the source code you can see that [`xcom_pull()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d80d52acf14034b0adf00e45b0fbac6ac03ab593/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L2328) uses `Xcom.get_many()` and `get_many` creates a filter using `IN` which allows to compare against multiple values. You can see the relevant code lines [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/279565022b94d2dc8a1ae0f7dd6bf4d1dd10dbdc/airflow/models/xcom.py#L447-L448).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In the example above I've mentioned `task_ids: Optional[Union[str, Iterable[str]]]` (see the example code `# pulls multiple values but from multiple tasks`) but this is not what I was looking for... I'm looking for a method to read multiple keys at once written to the XCOM by a single task. For any `Xcom.get_many()` method I could not find a solution where it expects a list of keys, like this: `key: Optional[Union[str, Iterable[str]]] = XCOM_RETURN_KEY`.

Comment: I misread sorry.. edited.